# JavaScript: is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in fact NOT a safe integer?

Tags: javascript, numbers

While performing some tasks with bit manipulations on HackerRank, I noticed a strange thing: despite the limit of numbers up to 10 ** 15 in a task (which is about 9 times smaller than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`), some test cases fail if not to use `BigInt` – although **neither source numbers, nor product numbers of such operations exceed max safe integer**. Then, I tried by hand the following in a browser console, and here is what the result was (it really surprised me):

```
507199254740991 >> 1 // -1011589121 (wrong, although 507199254740991 is about 18 times less than max safe integer)
Number(507199254740991n >> 1n) // 253599627370495 (correct)
Math.floor(507199254740991 / 2) //253599627370495 (correct)

638621066001121 ^ 907368627742749 // -1250667780 (wrong)
Number(638621066001121n ^ 907368627742749n) // 419934881731324 (correct)
```

Why does it happen? Is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in fact not a safe integer? It still it is, then why some operations with numbers fitting within this range fail? Is this a bug of JavaScript or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary operators (`>>` and `^` among others) cast number operands to 32bit integers first, then perform the operation based on that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And what does casting operands to 32bit integers mean in this context? How does it influence the limits?

Comment: Well, as `10 ** 15 > 2 ** 31`, you cannot use numbers to solve this problem.